# How to modify a JSON to a particular SQL query format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a requirement to modify a JSON to a JSON having the values in a SQL query format. To better explain.

```
{
    "Assets": {
        "ASSOCIATES_NAME": ["David", "Philip"],
        "CAR_NAME": ["Verron"]
    }
  , "Product":{"SELLER_NAME": ["XXXXX"]}
}
```

The result should be having the json values as an sql query leaving the keys as it is. So the resulting query will be:

```
{
  Assets: "(ASSOCIATES_NAME = 'David' OR ASSOCIATES_NAME = 'Philip') AND CAR_NAME = 'Verron'", 
  Product: "SELLER_NAME = 'XXXXX'"
}
```

I tried something but I couldn't figure it out well. Below it is:

```
console.log(Object.entries(a).map(x => {return {
  [x[0]]: `${Object.keys(x[1])} = '${Object.values(x[1])}'`,
  }}))
```

However I still need to figure out how to group individual values of an array. Any elegant ES6 based solution to this?. Please folks help me out on this. TIA

Comment: Consider parsing the JSON string? `JSON.parse`. Also, I'm not sure why you would need regex in this situation.

Comment: Yes I parsed the string. however the problem lies with the values.... I tried numerous ways like Object.entries, values etc.

Comment: Please may you share those previous tries. Making a simple [mcve] of each try is best.

Comment: Just a warning: Please be very careful of [SQL Injection](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection) attacks when handling raw SQL queries in the frontend.

Comment: @evolutionxbox shared. please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over the outer object properties and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the inner object properties to generate the `OR` and `AND` expressions:

```js
const json = `{
    "Assets": {
        "ASSOCIATES_NAME": ["David", "Philip"],
        "CAR_NAME": ["Verron"]
    }
  , "Product":{"SELLER_NAME": ["XXXXX"]}
}`
const params = JSON.parse(json);

const whereItems = Object.entries(params)
  .reduce((c, [k, v]) => {
    c[k] = Object.entries(v)
      .map(([param, value]) => '(' + value.map(v => param + " = '" + v + "'").join(' OR ') + ')')
      .join(' AND ');
    return c;
  }, {});
console.log(whereItems);
```

Note that it does produce unnecessary `()` around the single comparisons (e.g. `(SELLER_NAME = 'XXXXX')`), if you really want to get rid of them just condition the addition of those characters on `value.length > 1`.

Comment: (You could use a template string to avoid the backslashes?)

Comment: @evolutionxbox indeed. that's a lot cleaner; I've edited it in. thanks.

Comment: Oh good heavens. Thanks a lot @Nick. You saved my day. Just made a minor change as suggested by @evolutionxbox  `${value.map(v => param + " = '" + v + "'").join(" OR ")}`

Comment: Yeah.... @Nick what are your thoughts when the value is not array but just a string if in case of a single value. like ["Verron"] would be just "Verron"

Comment: You'd need to edit the code that dealt with `value` to check if it was a string or an array,  possibly simplest to just turn it into an array if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

upvote for @nik's answer,
here is just another way for beginners.

```
f3 = function(key, arr){
var result = arr.map(function(e) {
  return(`${key}='${e}'`)
})
if(result.length > 1)
  return(`(${result.join(' AND ')})`)
else
  return(result)
}

f2 = function(json) {
  var result = []
  for(const key in json) {
    result.push(f3(key, json[key]))
  }
  return(result.join(' OR '))
}

f = function(json) {
  var result = {}
  for(const key in json) {
    result[key] = f2(json[key])
  }
  return(result)
}
```

call f over your json